# How to check an element type with chai?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, chai

I want to check whether an element is an a or a div, how do I accomplish this?
this code is not working:

```
it('has no link if required', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<AssetOverlay asset={ assetsData[0] } shouldBeLinked />);
        expect(wrapper.find('.overlay-asset-link')).to.be.a('a');

        const wrapper1 = shallow(<AssetOverlay asset={ assetsData[0] } shouldBeLinked="false" />);
        //expect(wrapper1.find('.overlay-asset-link')).to.be.a('div');
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Well thats because chais type checking checks for **javascript** types, not for HTML-Tags.

In case `wrapper.find()` returns a normal HTML-Element, you could achieve what you want to test with:

`expect(wrapper.find('.overlay-asset-link').tagName).to.equal('A');`

*Note*: The tagname-property is always uppercase.