# Cypress get the element tag name by css selector

Tags: cypress

Simple question. How do I test (with `cypress`) that the element I query with a css selector is a `h2` for example?

`cy.get('.qards-widget-hero').first()// this needs to be a h2`

Comment: Can you show us a fragment of your HTML? Am I reading correct that you want to make sure the first element with the class qards-widget-hero should be a h2 element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you show us a fragment of all the HTML?

If I read your questions correct you want to make sure h2 exist. You say needs to be a h2, I think exist would do the same thing. I assume this widget is a h2 and has the class qards-widget-hero.

```
cy.get('h2.qards-widget-hero').should('exist')
```

//If you want the first one

```
cy.get('h2.qards-widget-hero').first().should('exist')
```

Answer (score 14):

@Maccurt's answer works for scenarios where there are no other element with the selected class, but if there is the following the test will report a false positive.

```html
<h1 class="qards-widget-hero"></h1>
<h2 class="qards-widget-hero"></h2>
```

See this question [How to check an element type with chai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36618846/how-to-check-an-element-type-with-chai).

I think you could use something like

```js
cy.get('.qards-widget-hero').first()
  .should('have.prop', 'tagName' ).should('eq', 'H2') // tagName is uppercase
```